TFS in VS - how to remove all included files with no changes?
I know there's an option to remove all included files that have no changes, without having to manually check each, but I just can't find it, and I can't find the answer anywhere.
I am using VS 2022.
I think it's supposed to be somewhere in the Pending Changes tab in Team Explorer.
I tried looking at all the options there available but I can't see the functionality I'm looking for.

What kind of repo are you using? TFVC or Git repo?

I am not using a Git repo. Isn't that a different source control from TFS? If I modify a file and save it, it appears in Pending Changes. If I undo the changes and save the file, it still shows up in Pending Changes even though, comparing the file with the original, there are no changes.
I'm not sure what other info would be relevant, I know there's an option to clear all unmodified files, but I can't find it. Maybe it's a command line option? I can't remember...

Maybe I'm missing or mixing things up, so to clarify - I am using TFS (TFVC?), there's no Git involved.

Got it. You should use the TFVC repo. I will check the option in VS.

Please check the answer below and check if the option: Undo pending changes -> Not to ALL  in VS2022 can work for you.


there's an option to remove all included files that have no changes, without having to manually check each, but I just can't find it,

Based on your description, you should be looking for the option: Undo pending changes -> Not to ALL when using TFVC repo.
Test it in VS2022 and the Option is valid.
For example:
Right click your solution and select Undo Pending Changes

Then you can click Not to ALL option.
For example:

Refer to this blog: TFS undo checkout of unedited files

You just need to "Undo pending changes" on checkout files. When undo to a first "actually edited" files, will pop up a asking window to ask you "if you want to discard the changes". Select "Not to all" and all unedited files will be undo the checkout, and leaving all the files you actually edited.

Note: DOES NOT SELECT added or deleted files when using the option: Undo pending changes  to remove all included files that have no changes  as the changes will be undone.
For example:


Right, it was a workaround.
What a confusing, mindbending solution, to "NOT UNDO" everything. Especially freaky when working with a large changeset that include tens of files and you have to triple-check to make sure that you DO NOT SELECT added or deleted files, as the changes will be undone.
I have selected the answer as correct, but can you please edit your answer with a warning to ensure that whoever does this DOES NOT SELECT added or deleted files, as it can undo hours and hours and hours of work, with a simple click?

It's a really good reminder. I have updated the answer. Thanks you.

If you are using Gated Checkin with TFVC, there is a "Reconcile Workspace" command in Visual Studio that will undo files from your workspace that are no longer different from the server after the gated checkin has completed.  This was informally known as "Undo Unchanged" files.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/check-folder-controlled-by-gated-check-build-process?view=azure-devops#reconcile-the-latest-changes-in-your-workspace-after-a-gated-check-in
There was once an "Undo Unchanged" command in the TFVC power tools, but I don't think it ever made it into the TFVC integration in Visual Studio.
